# How does CM & CD server communicates in sitecore?

Tags: amazon-ec2, sitecore, sitecore-mvc

I am new to sitecore and just trying to understand its architecture/design. Just curious to know how Intranet and Internet server communicates and how does the data flow happens between these two layers in on-prem and on AWS EC2 environment? I have surfed enough in the web and couldn't find the appropriate explanation.

Really appreciate if anyone can help me understand.

Answer (score 1):

When u do a publish from CM, it puts a record in eventqueue table in Web Db.
all CD servers will hit the eventqueue table table for update and proceed.

default is 2 seconds once this hit happens.

Answer (score 0):

In short, they communicate via events in the database(s). Note: This is very simplified but seeing it this way helped me understand how the events work and troubleshoot issues.

For example, when publishing an item, the publisher (running on CM or on a dedicated role) reads its data from the master database and writes it to the web database. When done, it raises an event by writing a row in the `EventQueue` table in web database. The CD server(s) picks up this event and clears its corresponding caches etc. causing a reload of that data from the web database.

All Sitecore databases have the `EventQueue` table and events goes to the table in different databases, depending on the type of event. An events is basically just a class name and a set of serialized data. Events can be raised "locally" and "globally" indicating if several instances should pick up the event. Think of a scenario where you have two CD servers sharing one web database, both CD's would have to pick up the event.

To keep track on what events has been processed, a "EQSTAMP" value is stored in the `Properties` table. It's named `[database]_EQSTAMP_[InstanceName]`. It's therefore essential that not two Sitecore instances share the same instance name. If not set, Sitecore will make an instance name by combining the hostname and IIS site name. The decimal `Value` of this timestamp corresponds to the hexadecimal `Stamp` column in the `EventQueue` table.

Normally, you should never have to play with these tables yourself, but I find it good to have some insights in how they work and keep an eye on them. They can grow in size and cause some issues. The `CleanupEventQueue` scheduled task is responsible for removing old processed events from the `EventQueue` tables. You may want to play with the scheduling of this agent if your `EventQueue` grows too large between cleanups.

Note: This is the most common way of communication between the servers. Later versions of Sitecore have other techniques as well, such as Rebus.

Answer (score 0):

[Event Queues. Why? How? When?](https://github.com/mitikov/KeepSitecoreSimple/wiki/Event-Queues.-Why-%3F-How-%3F-When-%3F) article that explains it in detail, it also describes the pitfalls of using this mechanism in real life as well.

Please also be aware that [Sitecore.Link](https://sitecore.link/) project is a good place to get more knowledge regarding Sitecore functionality.

It accumulates Sitecore knowledge all around the web.

Thanks.